# How to access a php variable outside of IF block

Tags: php, scope

I am trying to access a variable outside of if block in myphp code.

Here is my code;

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM content order by id DESC");  
          $result->execute();
          $dataArr = array(); 
          $result = $result->get_result();        
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        $userID = $row['uid'];


//get user name from another table

             $name = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM registered_users where id = ?"); 
            $name->bind_param("i",$userID); 
          $name->execute();        
          $getName = $name->get_result(); 
          if(($getRowCount = $name->num_rows) == 1){
            $resultRow = $name->fetch_assoc();
              $FirstName = $resultRow['first_name'];
        }


            array_push($dataArr , array("name"=>$FirstName));
          }
```

So it throws me an error on line array_push saying :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: FirstName in /home/path/path/file.php on line <line>
```

Is there a way I can get to access this variable as it is from even outside the if block if that is indeed the issue. Also I have followed other post on stackoverflow regarding this, but none of them seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need declare variable `$FirstName` before the `if` to set value an access to these on your `Array_push`

```
$FirstName = ''; // declare variable before the if
          if(($getRowCount = $name->num_rows) == 1){
            $resultRow = $name->fetch_assoc();
              $FirstName = $resultRow['first_name'];
        }


            array_push($dataArr , array("name"=>$FirstName));
          }
```

**ThanhPV Comment**
Or check variable defined by `isset()` function. (In case you don't want to use global scope) Like that:

```
array_push($dataArr , array("name"=>isset($FirstName) ? $FirstName : ""));
```

Comment: Or check variable defined by `isset()` function. (In case you don't want to use global scope)
Like that:
`array_push($dataArr , array("name"=>isset($FirstName) ? $FirstName : ""));`

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want this `variable` then just declare it out side of `if loop`. Simply set as a global variable.

```
<?php $FirstName = ''; ?>
```

then just assign it inside `if loop` and use it anywhere

also before using it just check it `empty` or not

```
if(!empty($FirstName)){
    array_push($dataArr , array("name"=>$FirstName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please declare the variable outside of loops if you are going to use it elsewere.`

```
    /* code before */
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM content order by id DESC");  
          $result->execute();
          $dataArr = array(); 
          $result = $result->get_result();        
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          $userID = $row['uid'];

//get user name from another table

          $name = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM registered_users where id = ?"); 
          $name->bind_param("i",$userID); 
          $name->execute();        
          $getName = $name->get_result(); 
          $FirstName = '';

    if(($getRowCount = $name->num_rows) == 1){
                $resultRow = $name->fetch_assoc();
                  $FirstName = $resultRow['first_name'];
            }
    array_push($dataArr , array("name"=>$FirstName));
      }
    /* code after*/
```

Now you have declared  `$FirstName` as static. So the value doesnt get destroyed even after exiting the `if loop`. And is re-initialized to null just before entering the if loop the next time.

hope i've helped. Do update the status.

Comment: if it returns blank, then it is caused by ` $FirstName = '  '; `

try a few debugging steps. to start with check if `$resultRow['first_name'];` returns a value.